# Can I use the same lock on multiple threads if they do not access the same variable?

Tags: python, multithreading, locking

Imagine I have two threads, each modifying a different variable. Can I pass the same lock object to them, or shall I use two separate locks? In general, when shall I use multiple locks?

Here is a toy example:

```
from threading import Thread, Lock
from time import sleep


def task(lock, var):
    with lock:
        var = 1
    sleep(5)


lock = Lock()

var1 = []
var2 = []

Thread(target=task, args=(lock, var1)).start()
Thread(target=task, args=(lock, var2)).start()
```

or is it better

```
lock1 = Lock()
lock2 = Lock()

var1 = []
var2 = []

Thread(target=task, args=(lock1, var1)).start()
Thread(target=task, args=(lock2, var2)).start()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only one thread can hold a lock at a time, and a lock is used to provide [mutually-exclusive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion) access to a piece of data (or variable).

Based on your example, where each thread accesses separate variables, you want two separate locks—one per variable. Note that if only one thread accesses a variable, though, you do not need to use a lock for it.

If you were to only use one lock, only one thread would be able to perform "work" at a time—even though their work is completely independent.

Comment: Thanks! That is the info I needed. Could you perhaps add a reference?

Comment: "Note that if only one thread accesses a variable, though, you do not need to use a lock for it." Sure, sure, that is a toy example. In the actual code, other functions may modify those variables.